# Send a variable from a JavaScript script inside my ASP.NET page to a C# Function in Code-Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have my ASP.NET C# Web site and i have some JavaScript script inside one of my pages, i already succeeded in calling a C# function from my Code Behind but i want to send some variable from my JavaScript script as an argument of the function.

Here is my code, including the C# function call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div /> ').text(message).html();
            var tremp_id = $('<div /> ').text("<%=Request.QueryString["trempid"]%>").html();

            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li class="<%=returnLiClass()%><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + "Tremp:" + tremp_id + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val('<%=returnName()%>');
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I'm calling the 'returnLiClass()' function (line 13) and i want to send the 'encodedMsg' var inside it.

How can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: One technique you can use, is to put your value in hidden field with the runat="server" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Place a function with name same as client method in your `Hub` class.

```
void broadcastMessage(string name, string message)
{
   //Do something here.....
}
```

Please note that the parameter name must be same.